# Windows Server 2012 Shares vs. Windows Explorer Sharing

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, file-sharing, permissions

When I use the server manager in WS2012 and create a new share, point it at a folder and give everybody permission to read, it works very strangely:
From a client computer, I can access the server in Windows Explorer (it prompts me for a password and lets me through), and then I see this list of shares. However, when I click on a share to access it, it asks me for a password again and this time it does not let me log in (Access denied), even though I know my credentials are correct.

However, I can also remove the share in sever manager, navigate to the shares folder in windows explorer, and right click a given folder, go to properties > sharing and share this folder. Then it works properly. On the client, I can see the list of shares and I can navigate it also.

What is the difference between these two approaches?